# Trying to identify a 1980's novel or short story about nuclear bomb detonation

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find a book or short story read in high school in the mid to late 80's -
Possibly US based, it centred around the actions of some survivors after a nuclear bomb has gone off.

I don't remember much in the way of detail other than a key part: During the description  of the event, there is reference to a radio that was playing. The story explained there was a coca-cola ad playing, and at the point of detonation/when the radio stopped, was where the ad was playing the jingle "Coke adds li...." (The bomb exploded as the ad was saying "life").

I think some of the story was also set where the characters where on foot after the blast trying to leave the area and some had bad burns, but there was little medical help (I may be mixing this up with something else though).

Comment: Do you remember any science fiction or fantasy elements to the story?

Comment: There are tons of stories of all lengths about nuclear war. Some more detail might be helpful.

Comment: I would think any "after the bomb" story (apart from WW2) has a SF element - just my opinion